# Using JavaFX to capture a video stream from the client browser

Tags: stream, video-streaming, javafx, video-capture, jmf

i am considering to build a web application that should let users record videos from their webcam and upload (or stream) to the website  server.

I know about JMF that should help me building the backend, but what about the front end? **Can JavaFX access webcams from browsers** as flex and silverlight do?

Comment: is anybody got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

No it can't and it doesn't seem to be on the official roadmap yet. But there is a feature request supported by many people. You can see and vote for it [here](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-3458)

Answer (score -1):

Java can, so JavaFX should be able to, as JavaFX 2.0 is now a java framework/library.